# how to make stylesheet appear in theme editor?

Tags: css, html-editor

I have a stylesheet in my theme in the css subdir of the theme dir (`css/style.css`). The question is how to make this .css file appear in the theme editor of the WordPress admin. (I know using the web editor is a bad idea and I never use it, but the client specifically asked for this).

Note: the only css file that shows up by default in my theme editor is 'style.css' of the root theme dir, but this is not what I need.

Comment: Have you tested this in WordPress 3.4? It's the first version to support template files in subfolders and so I wonder whether it would also address your issue.

Comment: Check this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/73068/12615

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it's impossible...

For one, there's no hook inside the file `/wp-admin/theme-editor.php`.

And last but not least, if you try one of this, it dumps an error:

- `/wp-admin/theme-editor.php?file=css%2Fstyle.css&theme=twentyeleven`
- `/wp-admin/theme-editor.php?file=css/style.css&theme=twentyeleven`

Case you find a workaround, this code injects a link to the desired file:

```
/**
 * Adjust the if('Twenty Eleven' == sel) to your theme name
 */
add_action('admin_head-theme-editor.php', 'wpse_55949_script_enqueuer');

function wpse_55949_script_enqueuer(){
    echo <<<HTML
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
        var sel = $("#theme option:selected").text();
        if('Twenty Eleven' == sel) 
        {
            $('<li><a href="theme-editor.php?file=css/style.css&amp;theme=twentyeleven">Subfolder Stylesheet<br><span class="nonessential">(css/style.css)</span></a></li>').appendTo('#templateside ul:last');
        }
    });     
    </script>
HTML;
}
```

---

**[update]**

An alternate approach would be to [create an options page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=create%20options%20page) where the client can [write/manipulate](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=theme%20options%20CSS) the CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet. I just offered brain-dead-simple instructions for editing the file via ftp or ssh and offered to create an options page that will also address other customizability problems ...but I'll wait a bit more for a simple answer to this

Comment: A lot of time has passed since this question got answered, but the approach above works for at least showing the link to the stylesheet in the backend. However, when clicking on the backend link to the sub-folder stylesheet I get a message stating that the file cannot be edited. I would assume it has something to do with WP rights to edit in specific folders. Is there a way to circumvent this?

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as you might think.

All the selectors that you wanted to give to a client, place in an extra stylesheet, *client-styles.css*

Save this stylesheet not inside the css folder, but in the theme root. So with the probably already existing *style.css* and *editor-style.css*.

Add `@import "client-styles.css";` to the *style.css* file (there's probably other import at-rules there already).

Correct link in the header from `/css/client-styles.css` to `/client-styles.css`

Remind the client that they can trash the site if they're not careful (as you said, they wanted this!).