# How to see files in directories in "Edit Themes" screen

Tags: themes, editor

I like to have folders in my theme folder for scripts and styles, but I can't access these folders in the "Edit Themes" interface. This is problematic for clients that don't give me FTP access. Is there a way to see these folders and the files in them from the Wordpress admin section?

Comment: Why do you must use the `theme editor` from WordPress? You easily can create a custom page for showing such files, and add a visual editor (whatever you want) to that for coding as you like.

Comment: Clients who don't give you FTP access are bad clients, or they're giving you better ways such as shell access. Chances are its a social issue because they lack the knowledge to know what FTP is so they're covering their arses. Demand access to the things that you need te be able to do your job, afterall you dont pay a plumber to fix your sink but deny entry to the house

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [how to make stylesheet appear in theme editor?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/55949/12615)

Comment: simply add `file_put_contents(get_template_directory() .'/template-custom-page.php', 'temporary content');` to an existing template.  Visit that page and it will create the file for you (if the web server user can create files).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is not a way to do this without modifying the core.

You should see `.php` files that are in subdirectories, but you won't see anything above the root theme directory for `.css` files, and you won't see any JavaScript files.

If you take a look at [`wp-admin/theme-editor.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/theme-editor.php), the relevant lines are...

```
<?php
$allowed_files = $theme->get_files( 'php', 1 );
$has_templates = ! empty( $allowed_files );
$style_files = $theme->get_files( 'css' );
$allowed_files['style.css'] = $style_files['style.css'];
$allowed_files += $style_files;
```

`$theme` is is a [`WP_Theme`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Theme) object representing the current theme.  It's create a few lines above.

The `get_files` method searches a directory by matching the the file extension (first argument) and using the depth (second argument).  The first call to `get_files` fetches all PHP files in the theme directory as well as the any subdirectories one level above the theme directory.

The second fetches all css files in the theme directory but it doesn't recursively go into subdirectories (notice the lack of the `$depth` argument).

There's not much you can do about this; there is a conspicuous lack of any calls to `apply_filters` and `do_action` in `theme-editor.php` and the `get_files` method lacks them as well. You're pretty limited.

And when PHP doesn't work, time to try the ugly JavaScript hacks!

Unfortunately, that's no good either. I tried exploring adding files to the list via JavaScript and ajax, but clicking on a JS added file results in an error message due to function called `validate_file_to_edit` which checks the current file to edit against the list of `$allowed_files` (see the above code that fetches that).

Answer (score 5):

The [Advanced Code Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-code-editor) plugin provides this functionality.

*From the plugin description:*

> Enables syntax highlighting in the integrated themes and plugins source code editors. Supports PHP, HTML, CSS and JS.
>   Effectively edit your themes or plugins when you only have access to a browser, by enabling syntax highlighting in WordPress integrated source code editors. Supports PHP, HTML, CSS and JavaScript

---

**Edit:**
The plugin mentioned above doesn't seem to have the directory tree for themes; only plugins. There is, however, another plugin that *does* provide this functionallity: [WPide](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wpide/)

*From the plugin description:*

> File tree allowing you to access and edit any file in your wp-content folder (plugins, themes, uploads etc)

There has also been a [trac ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/4131) on this topic; hopefully this will be fixed in a future version of WordPress.

Comment: That's still not what he's looking for - this plugin only changes the appearance of the editor and indeed adds some pretty cool features to it, but it still doesn't let him edit all of the files found within his theme directory(which the actual problem is)

Comment: There should be a directory tree to the right of the page... you can access all css, js, html and php files there

Comment: Wow, cool plugin and it is from a WPSE fellow: [@bainternet](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/2487/bainternet) :)

Comment: But @NikolaIvanovNikolov is right, no sub-folder editing for themes. The plugins editor does have it, but so does a plain installation. ..... Nikola, it seems that there's really no solution for that, apart from hac*ing the c*re or **creating a custom options page** to handle custom CSS (if that was the case).

Comment: The [WPide](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wpide/) plugin seems to support a directory tree for themes.

Comment: That Trac ticket was closed as fixed 4 years ago; 14175 is similar but was closed 19 months ago as a duplicate (of what is not specified). It appears the consensus is that this *is already fixed*.

Answer (score 0):

I do the same thing as you and organize things in folders. I never use that editor but I just took a look at one of my sites and I can see the files but not the directories. That is, the files are listed as present and are editable, but they are not displayed by directory. You can't tell what folder they are in unless you read the URL for the links.

If you are talking about a child theme, I am having trouble seeing some of the files and I don't know why. The owner, group, and permissions match on the parent theme, whose files I can see, and the child theme, some of whose files I can't see. I'd never noticed the issue until this question came up.

Comment: I don't see any files that are in a directory at all! e.g. in my css/ folder, I have 'style.css', 'style-med.css', and 'style-mobile.css'. None of these are visible from the "Edit Themes" page :(

Comment: I verified my answer by checking another site on a different server. However, on a third site I am having trouble seeing some of the files for a child theme but not the parent theme. Would that be related to your case?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem for all users.

Therefore, update to WordPress 3.4.x if you haven't already.

Remember that css/style.css will alphabetically appear under 'c', but separated out under Styles at the bottom.

If this doesn't work, try the same theme on a localhost install - if it works there it could be that their server doesn't allow recursive listing.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem almost every day with our WordPress customers.

I use a plugin that allows you to edit all files of WordPress. But it is not safe for accounts on  shared hosting (sometimes plugin allow edit any files on whole server).

This plugin has been removed from wordpress.org (I think for security reasons) and the author's domain now expired. I've found small review here:
http://www.themepremium.com/access-ftp-from-wordpress-dashboard-using-myftp-wordpress-plugin/

Below I'll post a link to a copy of the plugin.

**NOTE:**  *I  haven't any relations to the author of this plugin  and have not modified it. I will not be held responsible for how you use the plugin.*

["myftp" plugin](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4075272/myftp.zip)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have FTP access but you can use a little hack in the theme editor...

Simply add the following code to an existing template:

```
<?php
@file_put_contents(get_template_directory() .'/template-custom-page.php', 'temp content');
?>
```

Visit a URL that is using the template where you added the code to create the file and it should create the file for you (assuming the web werver user has permission to create files in the theme folder).

Remove the added code from the 1st template (after the file is create) otherwise the code will always erase the file content when executed.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for more recent information, **AceIDE** (forked from the now unmaintained WPide) works pretty well for quick and dirty edits.

Keep in mind that theme and plugin edits will be overwritten by updates, so editing this way is bad practice.

Answer (score -1):

If a client won't or can't give you FTP access then you shouldn't be working for them. You could take the time it would take to hack the core and just find better clients.

Comment: Sorry, but, IMO, this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: No worries, I can't comment on other answers otherwise I would have just done that.

Comment: ouch.. I never learn that... sorry :/

Comment: Meh...don't worry about it. It's more of a flaw with the scoring of SO-type sites. When you're below 50 you can't comment on questions or anything like that. In fact, I only commented on this question because anything to do with touching the core files is a huge red flag for me so I had a knee-jerk reaction. Cheers buddy!